# Different latitude/ longitude from same location with Google Maps API and Android SDK

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

We are seeing issue with google location (Andorid SDK)/maps API when request latitude/ longitude for same location name. In Mobile ( Android SDK) or Maps we are seeing for same location, different latitude/ longitude are return.

Example of location , latitude / longitude

Mobile - Andorid SDK
Web - Google maps API

> BDA Complex, HSR Layout, Bangalore, Karnataka, India
>   web [latitude] => 12.9137559 [longitude] => 77.6372802
>   mobile  [latitude] => 12.9137559 [longitude] => 77.6372802

> OpCord Consultancy Services Pvt Ltd, Bangalore, Karnataka, India
>       web     [latitude] => 12.9715987 [longitude] => 77.5945627
>       mobile  [latitude] => 12.91877 [longitude] => 77.651796

> Silk Board Junction, Madivala, Bangalore, Karnataka, India
>       web     [latitude] => 12.909404 [longitude] => 77.628569
>       mobile  [latitude] => 12.9172909 [longitude] => 77.6229143

> Mindspace, Hitech City, Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, India
>       web     [latitude] => 17.4414836 [longitude] => 78.3806675
>       mobile  [latitude] => 17.4414836 [longitude] => 78.3806675

Thanks,
Vikas Jagetiya

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6101

Comment: What are you using for geocoding the android.location.Geocoder or the Geocoding web-servcie?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response we were using  in our web server we are using  Gecode web serices  URL : http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address="

Comment: In APK using Geocoder API

In WebServer using
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address="   Sometime when gecoder give 0 lat/long, in those cases our web server will extract lat/long using maps api, and some time we find difference in lat/long as mentioned above and because of that   even though place distance ( calculated based on two lat/long ) is 1 KM, it shown 7-8 KM.